# Get all woocommerce comments/reviews

Tags: plugins

What I need to achieve is to get all comments from all products in Woocommerce.

This is not getting me ANY comments at all...

```
<?php $comments = get_comments( array( 'post_type' => 'product') ); ?>
```

However

```
<?php $comments = get_comments( array( 'post_id' => '4169') );
```

Gets me comments for particular product ID. How to query ALL comments?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Please try this:

```
 $args = array( 
                'number'      => 100, 
                'status'      => 'approve', 
                'post_status' => 'publish', 
                'post_type'   => 'product' 
        );

 $comments = get_comments( $args );
```

where you can edit the number of comments to your needs.

### Debug:

Maybe something is changing it via the `pre_get_comments` hook?

To debug it you can check out the SQL query with:

```
 global $wpdb;
 printf( '<pre>%s</pre>', $wpdb->last_query );
```

where you add this directly below the above `get_comments()` code snippet.

Also check the `edit-comments.php` screen if the comments show up there and their status.

Comment: Still 0 results...

Comment: And the WC _Recent Reviews_ widget shows also an empty list?

Comment: I always do it this way and it's working, it's like the widget does it. The problem must be something else. @kroma

Comment: [Here](http://docs.woothemes.com/wc-apidocs/source-class-WC_Widget_Recent_Reviews.html#_WC_Widget_Recent_Reviews) is the source of that widget

Comment: Yeah now i see WC Recent Reviews also show no results... any ideas?

Comment: btw do woocommerce reviews should also appear in native Comments section in WP admin?

Comment: Please check the updated answer.

Comment: Maybe you can share the SQL query? Did you see the comments on the `edit-comments.php` screen?

Comment: @birgire - thanks for the debug. Figured out that WPML was causing problems - Products weren't check to be translatable. After making them translatable works fine. +1

Comment: ok great to hear it's solved, thanks for sharing the cause of the problem.

Answer (score 1):

You'll need to loop through all comments and display them. Something like this will do the trick:

```
        $args = array( 
            'status'      => 'approve', 
            'post_status' => 'publish', 
            'post_type'   => 'product' 
        );

        $comments = get_comments( $args );

        foreach( $comments as $comment ) :
            echo( $comment->comment_author . '<br />' . $comment >comment_content);
        endforeach;
```

You can also pass in the 'number' parameter if you want to specify how many comments to show. Default is null (no limit).

Answer (score 0):

Woocommerce [overrides comment queries](http://docs.woothemes.com/wc-apidocs/source-class-WC_Comments.html#49-82), which seems to impact WC_Comment_Query and get_comments(), by filtering out shop comments directly in the SQL.

Adding the below before using WC_Comment_Query prevented shop comments from being excluded in my query.

```
remove_filter('comments_clauses', array( 'WC_Comments' ,'exclude_order_comments'), 10, 1 );
```